# Using MapReduce for Federated Learning

Tags: pyspark, pytorch, mapreduce, federated-learning

I would like to build a federated learning system with PyTorch. I've currently worked out and written the code for the following:

1. Finetuning models on client devices
2. Sending back the finetuned models to a master server that saves them to a storage bucket
3. Averaging the finetuned models (add all weights and divide by the number of models)

I want to parallelize the averaging step with MapReduce. In my opinion, the map step can divide all the weights by the total number of models, and the reduce step can sum all the resulting weights to give an averaged model.

I want to do this using PySpark, however I'm unable to figure out how to load model files (which are generally saved as Pickle files) with PyTorch in the Spark scripts. I was thinking of passing the model locations as values with the same key. All the Spark examples I find online only work with text files, so I'd appreciate some help regarding this.